Generate a very short noticeable pulse on human skin
Unfortunately I'm not an electrical engineer, but I have an idea that seems quite easy to make, but when searching for practical information I get lost in all jargon. I'm hoping for an answer that can validate my idea and point me in de direction on how to build it.
The idea: have something like a sweatband on your wrist that is fitted with 4 electrodes that can generate a small pulse. One on each side of your wrist. The goal is that I can detect which of the electrodes were turned on just by feeling the pulse.
What would I need for a simple proof of concept setup? How can I turn something like a 9V battery into a pulse generator on the push of a button.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

A pulse circuit running on 9 V is a very common thing.  You'll get many replies using something called  "555".  But 9 V probably is not enough voltage to push enough current to be felt.  Muscle stimulators called a TENS unit do this, but they use conductive pads that are wet to increase conduction.  IOW, the circuit is easy; the sweatband is the problem.

recurring pulses, or one pulse per button press?

AND because somebody has to bring it up, "patient contact" electronics are dangerous.  UL has a separate bunch of rules just for this.  Granted, 9 V on the skin surface is relatively safe, but anyone who knows how to do what you want is gonna want to know a whole lot more about what you are trying to achieve.

Go research these questions first, then maybe someone can help with a circuit suggestion.  What is the minimum voltage applied to electrodes on sweaty wet skin that is potentially hazardous (i.e. could cause a burn or damage nerves) and is there current level below which is considered non-hazardous?  Perhaps there is an applicable standard for medical application of electrical stimulation?   Are humans more sensitive to direct current or alternating current passed through skin between electrodes?  If alternating current, what frequency of current/voltage has the peak sensitivity?

Why electrical pulse? Why not tiny vibration motor?

Thanks for all comments! I'll continue my research.
